# How can I stop/pause a function from another function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple jquery-ui slider which I am continuously automatically looping through values. I successfully have a button which starts the movement, but I forget how I can pause/stop the movement when another button is pressed? 
I know this is something really simple, but am having an absolute mind blank and google is not giving me what I want. (probably because i'm searching for the wrong wording). What can do I put in the pauseSlider function to ... pause the slider!

```
function scrollSlider() {
    var slideValue;
    slideValue = $("#slider").slider("value");
    if (slideValue >= 0) {
        if (slideValue == 2013) {
            slideValue = -1;
        }
        $("#slider").slider("value", slideValue + 1);
        console.log($("#slider").slider("value"));
        setTimeout(scrollSlider, 1000);
    }
}

$('#startSlider').click(function() {
    scrollSlider();
});

$('#pauseSlider').click(function() {
    //What do I put in here?
});
```

Comment: you need to store the timer id from the result of `setTimeout`

Comment: check clearTimeout()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setTimeout` returns a random number which you'll have to store in a variable and then use it to clear the `setTimeout` in `$('#pauseSlider')`'s click handler.

```
var id;
function scrollSlider() {
   // (...) code 
   id = setTimeout(scrollSlider, 1000);
   // (...) more code
}
$('#pauseSlider').click(function() {
   clearTimeout(id);
});
```